How to realize CasADI optimization with an existing casadi::Function cost function?
I've already computed an optimization with NLopt using a CasADI cost function and gradient.
Now I want to compare the optimization performance of NLopt with other optimization libraries, starting with CasADI.
I already have the CasADI function for cost and gradient:
casadi::Function final_result_fun("final_result_fun",{u_sym,init_x_sym,obj_list_1_sym,obj_list_2_sym,dt_sym,cost_sym},{current_cost_sym, grad_cost_sym});

How can I re-use this function to perform the optimization with CasADI?
I don't quite understand how nlpsol works, and the official example is no help. I have found an optimization example using casadi::Callback, but eval needs std::vector< casadi::DM>, not casadi::Function.
Any help will be welcome.

CasADI isn't an optimization library, but it includes an IPopt optimizer (which I didn't manage to run).

I've finally used Acados which is designed to be used with CasADI. It is way faster than NLopt but it is harder to get good results since there are a lot of features/parameters that can be tuned.
